# jQuery basic toggling only working one way

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I've created some quick jQuery toggle code:

```
$("#expander.closed").click(function(){
    console.log("opening");
    $("#expander").removeClass();
    $("#expander").addClass("open");
});
$("#expander.open").click(function(){
    console.log("closing");
    $("#expander").removeClass();
    $("#expander").addClass("closed");
});
```

The idea is that everytime you click `#expander` the class toggles between `open` and `closed`.

However, for some reason, it only works once, changing from `closed` to `open`, and then goes no further.

I have no clue why. [Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4u9Vn/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in the beginning, when you bind the events, `.closed` class does not exists, so the event does not get bound

May be you should bind the event to some other criteria, or use `live`. which is deprecated though

Better way would be like this

```
$("#expander_parent").on('click', '#expander.closed', function(){
    // Do your stuff
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why would using the parent be a better way though?

Comment: JQuery `on` uses the parent delegate event trigger. But, I'd still go with the wirey's solution, which is simplified for your case. However, whenever you don't have elements at the time of binding the event and still want to be able to use it, use `on`

Comment: See this for your reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click

Answer (score 2):

Just bind it using the id and toggle the classes using [.toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

```
$("#expander").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('open closed');
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wT4mX/)

if you need to do other functions depending on which class it has you can check like this

```
$("#expander").click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('open closed');
    if($this.hasClass('open')){
       // do your open code
    }else{
       // do your close code
    }   
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bZx8a/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, in the wider scheme of things, I need to perform other functions related to which way the function has been toggled. (Basically, do some animations on one click, then on the other, reverse the animations.) Is there any way using this solution I can do anything like this? Cheers.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to know why my animation isn't working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4u9Vn/5/) would you? Thanks.

Comment: @ACarter You forgot the `#` in your selector [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/amZ9C/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this and add your other related operations within the if/else conditions

**HTML:**

```
<div id="expander" class="closed">Click Me</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.closed {
    background-color: red;
}

.open {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$("#expander.closed").click(function (){
    if ($('#expander').attr('class') === 'closed') {
          $('#expander').attr('class', 'open');

          // Add other related functions here
    } else {
        $('#expander').attr('class', 'closed');

        // Add other related functions here
    }    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mCDwy/1/